# How to get_posts having post thumbnail?

Tags: post-thumbnails, get-posts

I have following code:

```
$posts = get_posts(array(
  "meta_key" => "special",
  "meta_value" => "surprise",
  // "has_post_thumbnail" => true, // how to do that?
));
```

What should I do to select posts having [post thumbnails](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Thumbnails)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The thumbnail is stored as a meta with a key of `_thumbnail_id`, so that could be used to find posts that have thumbnails. Something like this:

```
$query = new WP_Query(array(
    'meta_query' => array( array( 
        'key' => '_thumbnail_id',
        'value' => '0',
        'compare' => '>=',
        )
    )
));
```